# How can I save the output of printf into a text file?

Tags: c, output

In Linux, I want to save a specific line into a text file. In the code, I have pointed out which line do I want to save. I have tried fopen() and fclose() but for some reasons it didn't work!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float convertCelFahrenheit(float c)
{
    return ((c * 9.0 / 5.0) + 32.0);
}
int main()
{
    FILE *output_file
    output_file = fopen("output.dat", "w"); // write only
    while (1)
    {
        int initChoice;
        printf("Press 1 to convert into Fahrenheit\nPress 2 to exit\nProvide Input: ");
        scanf("%i", &initChoice);
        if (initChoice == 2)
        {
            break;
        }
        else if (initChoice == 1)
        {
            float celsius, fahrenheit;
            int endChoice;
            printf("Enter temperature in Celsius: ");
            scanf("%f", &celsius);
            fahrenheit = convertCelFahrenheit(celsius);
            printf("\n%.2f degree Celsius = %.2f degree Fahrenheit", celsius, fahrenheit);

            // I want to save the above line e.g. the printf output into a text file

            fprintf(output_file, "\n%.2f degree Celsius = %.2f degree Fahrenheit", celsius, fahrenheit);
            printf("\n\nDo you want to calculate for another value?\n[1 for yes and 0 for no]: ");
            scanf("%d", &endChoice);
            if (endChoice == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(output_file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use `fprintf()`?

Comment: I tried using fprintf() in the place of printf() but it didn't work -_- 
Maybe I don't know how can I use fprintf() here

Comment: Show the actual code you tried that you thought would work but didn't. That is, provide a [complete minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I am in linux

Comment: FILE *output_file;
    output_file = fopen("output.dat", "w");
I tried it and output.dat is getting created as well but nothing is inside it

Comment: Don't add important info in the comments where it can't be formatted properly to make it readable. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68769243/edit) the question to update it. But  the code you have shown is still not complete - where is the `fprintf` that you claim you have called?

Comment: @Pritam Yeah, I was so fixated on path problems -- if you *create* a file the path doesn't really matter as long as you can write in the directory. And backslashes are typically not an issue in *nix file systems unless somebody sabotaged you by creating a file name with a backslash in it ;-). So just use fopen()/fprintf.

Comment: @kaylum I have updated the question/ Please check it

Comment: `fclose(output_file);` makes more sense BEFORE `return 0;` (though the stream will be closed on program exit regardless) Show the output of `cat output.dat`

Comment: cat output.dat gives nothing @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: Really the only problems with your code are the lack of validating the `fopen()` (e.g. `if (!output_file) { perror ("fopen-output_file"); return 1; }` and then the validation of EVERY input, e.g. `if (scanf("%i", &initChoice) != 1) { fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr); return 1; }`. The only problem that makes sense with `fopen()` is you do NOT have write permission in the present working directory -- validating the open and outputting the error will help narrow the issue.

Comment: Thank you!!!! Everyone! Now it is working!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `fprintf` instead of `printf` when you want to save to a file. `printf(...)` works like `fprintf(stdout, ...)`.

```
#include <errno.h> /* errno */
#include <string.h> /* strerror */

FILE *fout = fopen("myFile.txt", "w"); // The "w" is important - you want to open the file for writing.
if (!fout) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file for writing: %s\n", strerror(errno));
  return 1;
}
fprintf(fout, "\n%.2f degree Celsius = %.2f degree Fahrenheit", celsius, fahrenheit);
fclose(fout);
```

Comment: Please please please show the beginner that they need need need to check the return value of fopen().

Comment: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strerror’; did you mean ‘perror’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   20 |         fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file for writing: %s\n", strerror(errno));
      |                                                                  ^~~~~~~~
      |                                                                  perror


the output

Comment: If you are in Linux and included `string.h` at the top of the file, it should work. I also added some error checking (but not for fprintf although it may also fail if you run out of disk space)

Comment: adding string.h resolved the compiling issue. Still my output file is empty although the output file is getting created :( @sjoelund.se

Comment: Are you sure that you are running the newly compiled program? The program you now have in the question works fine for me (after adding a missing semicolon), including the expected output in the file.

Comment: @sjoelund.se my code had 2 cases and I added fprintf() in one case only and kept trying with that case only so every time the output came blank as I hadn't added fprintf() for that case yet! That was a very silly mistake from me.